# Issue with iframe in TinyMCE

Tags: plugin-development, wp-admin, tinymce, iframe

How does TinyMCE generate an iframe in the WordPress admin panel? Actually, I could not find out the starting point of the iframe which is generated by TinyMCE.

Comment: You can't directly, have you considered shortcodes instead? What's your reason for wanting an iframe in post content?

Comment: Thanks @TomJNowell for your reply. Actually I am doing bug fixing in a WordPress Plugin. I got an iframe there. But could not find how it is generated. The plugin is about shortcode.